# Why invalid ENUM value is allowed in strict mode

Tags: mysql

Mine is Mysql 5.5.37.
I created this table:

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
     status ENUM('active','blocked','nobalance','notfound','expired') NOT NULL
     )ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and ran this command

```
INSERT INTO test1 (status) VALUES ('active1');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)


>  select * from test1;
> +--------+ | status |
> +--------+ |        |
> +--------+ 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The strict mode is already set

```
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
+-------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.sql_mode |
+-------------------+
| STRICT_ALL_TABLES |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But as per [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) why no error on inserting invalid ENUM value?

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;` ?

Comment: Thanks, I should have set this variable "SET SESSION sql_mode 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES';" to have that work.